# Why pm2 logs not showing real time in Node js?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have tried used pm2 modules and use pm2 logs, early pm2 logs are real time and show me everything console it but from today show only at least 15 lines?( can change this line more or less but not show real time "pm2 logs --lines 1000" show at least 1000 but I want show real time logs )

when run "pm2 logs" showing :

> *[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
>   C:\Users\user.pm2\pm2.log last 15 lines:
>   PM2        | Error while getting network statistics Error: not supported
>   PM2        |     at process.nextTick (D:\wamp64\www...\pm2\node_modules\systeminformation\lib\filesystem.js:418:21)
>   PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   PM2        | Error while getting network statistics Error: not supported
>   PM2        |     at process.nextTick (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\systeminformation\lib\filesystem.js:418:21)
>   PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   PM2        | Error while getting network statistics Error: not supported
>   PM2        |     at process.nextTick (D:\wamp64\www...\pm2\node_modules\systeminformation\lib\filesystem.js:418:21)
>   PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   PM2        | Error while getting network statistics Error: not supported
>   PM2        |     at process.nextTick (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\systeminformation\lib\filesystem.js:418:21)
>   PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   PM2        | Error while getting network statistics Error: not supported
>   PM2        |     at process.nextTick (D:\wamp64\www...\pm2\node_modules\systeminformation\lib\filesystem.js:418:21)
>   PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)*

Why show this error and how resolve it? and why not showing real time logs for me?

all work done :

> kill pm2, restart it, update it, update node modules, flush pm2

Thank's